# can't get a coordinate on an element the Position:fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the **clicked** x and y position on **an image** and wanted the image to stay at the same position as I scroll up/down. The problem is the scripts/browser didn't know what to do because the position of the image if fixed. I am guessing if I can change it to the absolute position and monitor it as I go but the scrolling thing is not that smooth at all. Any ideas guys?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #AutoScrollDotNetImage
    {
     width: 500px;
      position: fixed;
      clear: both;*/
    }
    body
    {
      background-color: Silver;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#DotNetImage").click(function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
          $('#posx').html('<p>X Coordinate: ' + x + ', Y Coordinate: ' + y + "</p><p>e.pageX: " + e.pageX + "e.pageY: " + e.pageY + "</p><p>" + "this.offsetLeft: " + this.offsetLeft + "this.offsetTop: " + this.offsetTop + "</p>");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
      <td style="background-color: Gray">
        <div id="AutoScrollDotNetImage">
        <p> ELEMENT COORDINATE</p>
          <div id="posx">
           <p> scroll and click on google image</p>
        </div>
          <img id="DotNetImage" alt="No change" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />
    </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="clear: both; height: 5000px;">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `$('body').scrollLeft()` and `$('body').scrollTop()` in your position equation:

```
$("#DotNetImage").click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - $('body').scrollLeft() - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - $('body').scrollTop() - this.offsetTop;
    // ...etc
}
```

[**See updated fiddle →**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGMxM/3/)

Comment: The Y Coordinate is still incorrect. The y coordinate should be less than 364px and the x should be less than 126px. Tested by Firefox version 3.6

Comment: It's because of padding in the body and table, when taking that out it works: http://jsfiddle.net/HGMxM/3/   You might have to adjust the equation based on such padding, but the key is the scroll top and left.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your problem then because the X and Y coordinates are returning exactly what I'd expect within the range you specified.

Comment: my bad, thanks for trying. I was trying to determine the clicked coordinate on an image not the entire web page.